# how to convert curl command to python3 requests

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, curl, python-requests

Can anyone tell me how to convert this CURL command below to Python3 Requests module?

**Curl command** **:**

```
curl --header "Accept=application/json" --form 
               print_file=@a.gcode http://189.167.1.103/print_file_uploads
```

1. Actually I have to upload a Gcode file to 3D Printer.
2. I am succeeded with module OS. Here is how I did.

**Success** **:**

```
import os
ip_address = 189.167.1.103
file_name = "D:\networking\a.gcode"
os.system("curl --header "Accept=application/json" --form 
print_file=@%shttp://%s/print_file_uploads"%(file_name,ip_address))
```

but I don't want it to be done with OS module. Could you help me out to implement the same in python3 request?

Comment: please describe in detail what the initial curl command does, then im sure someone will gladly help you out

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can read [this](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)

So, example with request is:

```
import requests
response = requests.get('https://github.com/timeline.json')
response.json()
```

And possible solution for you would be something like:

```
import requests

url = 'http://189.167.1.103/print_file_uploads'
payload = open("D:\networking\a.gcode")
headers = {'Accept: application/json'}
response = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
```

Answer (score -1):

**This might work**-

import requests

access_token = 'xxxx'
device_id = 'xxxx'

address = 'https://api.spark.io/v1/devices/{0}/update/'.format(device_id)
data = {'access_token': access_token, 'args': '000000000000000'}

r = requests.post(address, data=data)

print(r.text)